# Track Structure Changes in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I want to track the schema changes made in a database. For example, when a new column is added to a table (weather from designer or script), a script should be generated like 'alter table tbl1 add col1 int' and so on.

I got to the Schema Changes History Report but it doesn't provide enough information required as it only shows the table changed, change type and date and time etc but does not provide the script which was generated to make that change.

Comment: Possibly a better solution is: Gate(control) who can make changes using permissions.  Otherwise lookup  https://autoaudit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got to the solution via this link. It is too easy to enable

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1723/auto-generate-change-scripts-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-for-tables/